# Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Xamarind android ADB2C

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I always get the below exception when calling Azure ADB2C using MSAL 2.2.0 below is the code snippet and the exception received. Note that all nuget packages are up-to-date and nothing required update

```cs
PublicClientApplication PCA = new PublicClientApplication(BL.Constants.ClientID, BL.Constants.Authority);

PCA.RedirectUri = BL.Constants.RedirectUri;

try
{

    //IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

    //var authenticationResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(BL.Constants.Scopes, new UIParent(this.Activity));

    var authenticationResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(
        BL.Constants.Scopes,
        "",
        UIBehavior.SelectAccount,
        "",
        null,
        BL.Constants.Authority,
        new UIParent(this.Activity));
}

catch (MsalException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message != null && ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
    {
        //await OnForgotPassword();
    }
    if (ex.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled")
    {
        //await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", "Exception message: " + ex.Message, "Dismiss");
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string test = ex.Message;
    throw ex;
}
```

Here is the constant file.

```cs
namespace BL
{
    public class Constants
    {
        // Replace strings with your own values
        // Azure Active Directory B2C
        public static readonly string Tenant = "tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"; // Domain/resource name from AD B2C
        public static readonly string ClientID = "clientid"; // Application ID from AD B2C
        public static readonly string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_SiUpIn"; // Policy name from AD B2C
        public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "" }; // Leave blank unless additional scopes have been added to AD B2C
        public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/"; // Doesn't require editing
        public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}"; // Doesn't require editing
        public static readonly string URLScheme = $"msal{ClientID}"; // Custom Redirect URI from AD B2C (without ://auth/)
        public static readonly string RedirectUri = $"{URLScheme}://auth"; // Doesn't require editing
    }
}
```

But I always get the below expception

`10-25 08:43:57.924 I/MonoDroid( 2850): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 10-25 08:43:57.936 I/MonoDroid( 2850): System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.) ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED 10-25 08:43:57.936 I/MonoDroid( 2850): at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-8/xamarin-android/external/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132 10-25 08:43:57.936 I/MonoDroid( 2850): at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00038] in :0 10-25 08:43:57.936 I/MonoDroid( 2850): at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0003e] in :0 An unhandled exception occured.`

Comment: Which version of `Xamarin.Android` is that being compiled with?

Comment: it is compiled with version 27.0.2.1 and the API level is 23 android 6.0. i have tried with android 8.1 Oreo API 27 and the same error.